# Dynamic deployment Angular. One docker image, multiple deployment

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, deployment

I need to find a way to deploy an Angular application dynamically, so that the same docker image allows me to do several deployments (development, staging, production) in which the access URL is modified.

I'm making an application in Angular 7 using Angular-cli 6.4.1.
For the deployment I am creating a docker multistage container where I build the image and configure it with nginx.

The problem is that for the deployment we use a private registry in which we use a proxy that handles redirections, so that my application would be deployed following the scheme: {SERVER_HOST} : {PORT} / {SERVER_LOCATION}

When I try to access that URL, only the index.html is loaded, since the rest of the resources are associated with the base path "/".

Angular provides an argument in the build (--base-href) that allows to modify the path of the entire application, however it does not help me since I need the same Docker image to allow me to perform different deployments so that the {SERVER_LOCATION} parameter is not always the same.

I have also tried to read the environment variables at runtime to modify the href attribute of the base tag, however it is difficult to execute a code that is in a file that is not loaded next to the index.

As a workaround I decided to create a function in the index that performs an ajax request that collects the configuration parameters in order to load the rest of the resources, however I do not like it since it breaks Angular's operation.

```
<-- This is working fine, but is not dynamic: -->
npm run build -- --prod --base-href https://myHost.net:8080/path/app/ --configuration=$configuration


<-- And this is working but is not Angular friendly -->

/** assets/data/appConfig.json */
{
    "SERVER_HOST": "https://myHost.net:8080",
    "SERVER_PATH": "/path/app/"
}

/** index.html */
<script>
  (function() {
    if (window.onerror) {
      loadConfig();
    }

    function loadConfig() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = 'assets/data/appConfig.json';
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
          window.appBaseHref = data.SERVER_PATH;
          document.getElementById("base").href = data.SERVER_PATH;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open('GET', url);
      xhttp.send();
    }
  })()
</script>
```

I have been told that there is an option to jump the proxy, but I can not find a way to do it, I do not know how to configure it. I think that maybe there is some kind of adjustment that can be made in the nginx configuration file so that the application "reads" from the provided URL and the base href of the application can always be kept as "/".

Currently my nginx.conf file is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location /documentation {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /documentation/index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Where location path '/' is my angular app and location path '/documentation' is reserved path for the project documentation.

Any kind of help will be welcome.

<--- Edit --->

During these days I have been trying several things, and the truth is that I'm quite confused about how to continue, since nothing seems to work.

I have configured Nginx to add  env $uri+$basepath property, but I realize that the relationship is just the opposite. I need my index.html to make requests to the proxy route instead of the path '/', because due to this, the request does not even enter the log (the proxy does not redirect me because it does not have the prefix of my app)

I'll give you the example:
My app is hosted at: myHost:8080/myapp/front
When I enter this url(myHost:8080/myapp/front), the app loads the index, but the associated resources (styles, runtime, polyfills, scripts and main) are not loaded because they send the request to: myHost:8080/{resourcePath} instead of to myHost:8080/myapp/front/{resourcePath}
[image]

At this point I do not know where to go. I would be able to get the result I want to put the flag --base-href /myapp/front, but I want this route to be dynamic and depend on my environment variable of the VIRTUAL_HOST system, which of course I do not know at the time of the build of the application

Next I paste my dockerfile and the nginx configuration file.

Dockerfile (The commented lines are the proposals that have not come to work in the expected way).

```
### STAGE 0: Based on Node.js, to build and compile Angular ###
FROM node:alpine as node

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the dependencies to install once and let Docker use the cache for the next builds
COPY package*.json /app/

# Install all dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy all the project into the image
COPY ./ /app/

# Argument to build the image according to the environment
ARG configuration=production

# Compiles our project
RUN npm run build -- --prod --configuration=$configuration

### STAGE 1: Based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx ###
FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*


## From 'builder' stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY --from=node /app/dist/dsa-frontend /usr/share/nginx/html

# Add directive
# COPY nginx-custom.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template

COPY nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# CMD /bin/bash -c "envsubst '\$VIRTUAL_SERVICE_LOCATION' < nginx-custom.conf > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx-custom.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /myapp/front$uri /myapp/front$uri/;
        # try_files $uri $uri/ $uri$VIRTUAL_SERVICE_LOCATION $uri$VIRTUAL_SERVICE_LOCATION/ /index.html;
    }

    location /documentation {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /documentation/index.html =404;
    }
}
```

But none of this seems to work.

Finally, we have made the decision to remove development from proxy and open a new port to deploy this application, so that the root path is now '/'.

And now all is working fine.

Comment: Were you not able to handle it in nginx conf ?. Please simplify the question.

Comment: I just edited the question. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: As you pointed out. you can dynamically provide the context root of the application through an environment variable and set it to nginx env $uri+$basepath where $basepath is to be populated based on deployment.

Comment: Also not to forget, nginx env variables can be passed while deploying the image.

Comment: use confd templates to go with nginx configuration. [confd](http://www.mricho.com/confd-and-docker-separating-config-and-code-for-containers/)

Answer (score 2):

I think I managed to get comprehensive (although probably **quite fragile** - feel free to recommend improvements!) solution to exactly the same problem: reusing one Angular/NGINX Docker image for multiple environments (hence multiple base routes).

Additionally I wanted to resolve the issue of accessing external APIs, so everything the application is requesting will go through the NGINX in the container, so you don't have to think about [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). In my example I have two things:

- Image server endpoint
- Socket.IO (WebSocket) endpoint

Client side routing works as expected with `ROOT_PATH` corresponding to `/`.

What I still did **not** try (but am going to):

- HTTPS (probably not much will change dramatically due to this)

The end result looks like this:

---

**Build and run container locally (once you have everything in place)**

`ROOT_PATH` is the parameter you were looking for.

`DNS_IP` is needed due to NGINX `proxy_pass`, you probably want to [substitute Google DNS with something else](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/743).

```sh
docker build . -t fancy-web-app && \
docker run -it --rm \
    --name fancy-web-app-configured \
    --publish target=80,published=80 \
    --env ROOT_PATH='staging' \
    --env WEBSOCKET_PATH='socket.io' \
    --env IMAGE_PATH='image' \
    --env API_URL='http://api.server.example.com/api/v1/' \
    --env DNS_IP='8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4' \
    fancy-web-app
```

---

I will list all things you need for clarity:

**NGNIX**

1. **nginx.conf**

   Modified during container startup, unusable otherwise, since it has references to environment variables.

**Docker**

2. **docker-entrypoint.sh** <-- * * * This is where the *magic* happens. * * *
3. **Dockerfile**

   [Multistage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), has `docker-entrypoint.sh` as a default [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) for the runtime stage.

**Angular**

4. **index.html**

   With default development configuration, modified during container startup, so it turns into "runtime configuration".
5. **app.conf.ts**

   Configuration allowing you to abstract away configuration in global variable and not bring this ugliness further into your services
6. **app.module.ts**

   Angular dependency injection allowing you to reference configuration in any service
7. **some-angular.service.ts**

   This is where you use injected configuration.

**Angular bonus points**

8. **proxy.conf.json**

   For working on localhost without containers (equivalent of nginx.conf for development, will be used by WebPack/`ng serve`)
9. **angular.json**

   Here you can specify proxy configuration once and have it everywhere by default.

---

If there is some interest, I can setup GitHub repository with all the needed parts in place (please comment/rate, so I could see there is a need for that).

---

**NGINX**

**1. nginx.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;

  # Serve static files (HTML, CSS, JS)
  location /${ROOT_PATH} {
    # Using `alias` insead of `root` directive, so ${ROOT_PATH}
    # will be discarded and static file will be fetched straight
    # from the specified folder
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  # Re-route calls to external APIs
  location  ~ ^/${ROOT_PATH}/(${WEBSOCKET_PATH}|${IMAGE_PATH})/(.*) {
    resolver ${DNS_IP};
    proxy_pass ${API_URL}/$1/$2$is_args$args;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  }

}
```

---

**Docker**

**2. docker-entrypoint.sh**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -eu

# Inject environment variables into NGINX configuration
# List all variables to be substituted to avoid clashing with
# NGINX own variables: https://serverfault.com/questions/577370
envsubst \
    '${API_URL} \
    ${ROOT_PATH} \
    ${WEBSOCKET_PATH} \
    ${IMAGE_PATH} \
    ${DNS_IP}' \
    < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template \
    > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Set correct HTML base tag, so static resources are fetched
# from the right path instead of the root path.
# NOTE: Trailing and leading slashes in base href are important!
# Using `~` separator to avoid problems with forward slashes
sed --in-place \
  's~<base href="/">~<base href="/'$ROOT_PATH'/">~' \
  /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

# Set WebSocket API endpoint
# Using `~` separator to avoid problems with forward slashes
sed --in-place \
  "s~webSocketPath.*,~webSocketPath: \`/$ROOT_PATH/$WEBSOCKET_PATH\`,~" \
  /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

# Set image API endpoint
# Using `~` separator to avoid problems with forward slashes
sed --in-place \
  's~imageBaseUrl.*~imageBaseUrl: `${window.location}'$IMAGE_PATH'`~' \
  /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

cat /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

exec "$@"
```

**3. Dockerfile**

```
# Produce static files
FROM node:10.15.3-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./package.json
COPY ./package-lock.json ./package-lock.json
RUN npm set progress=false && \
    npm install --silent
COPY . /app
RUN npm run ng build -- --prod --output-path=dist

# Use NGINX to serve static files and re-route requests
FROM nginx:1.15.10-alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=0 /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
EXPOSE 80
```

---

**Angular**

**4. index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fancy web app</title>
  <base href="/">
  <script>
    // These default values make sense when you `npm start`
    // They will be substituted during container startup
    // Using global variable on the window object here.
    // Is there a better way?
    window['app-config'] = {
      webSocketUrl: `${window.location.host}`,
      webSocketPath: `/socket.io`,
      imageBaseUrl: `${window.location}image`
    };
    console.log(window['app-config']);
  </script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <pdd-root></pdd-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**5. app.conf.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Configuration {
  webSocketUrl: string;
  webSocketPath: string;
  imageBaseUrl: string;
}

// Reading configuration out, so we have it Angular world 
export const AppConfiguration: Configuration = window['app-config'];
```

**6. app.module.ts** (snipped out not interesting details)

```js
import <--snip-->

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    <--snip-->
  ],
  imports: [
    <--snip-->
  ],
  providers: [
    <---snip-->
    SomeAngularService,
    { provide: Configuration, useValue: AppConfiguration },
    <---snip--->
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**7. some-angular.service.ts** (snipped out not interesting details)

```js
<--snip-->
export class BackendService {

  constructor(private configuration: Configuration) {

    const client = io(
      // Do not append route to the hostname
      // otherwise Socket.IO will treat it as `namespace`
      this.configuration.webSocketUrl,
      {
        // Do not auto-connect to exclude racing
        // between setup and connection
        autoConnect: false,
        // You have to specify route here
        path: configuration.webSocketPath
      });
      <--snip-->
```

---

**Angular bonus points**

**8. proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/socket.io/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000/socket.io/",
    "ws": true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": { "^/socket.io" : "" }
  },
  "/image/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000/image/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": { "^/image" : "" }
  }
}
```

**9. angular.json** -> see the last line before snip below

```
<--snip-->
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "fancy-web-app:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
<--snip-->
```